# where to create index on large table?

Tags: oracle, performance, query-optimization

I'm using Oracle 11g. I have table with hundreds of thousands of records.

My Query :

```
Select a1,a2,..... n 
from tbl 
where a1=val1 and a2=val2 and a3=val3 and a4=val4 and a5=val5
```

To improve query performance in where condition for which column I have to create index?

Comment: Normalization might be needed too. Why does your table use 5 different columns horizontally? How does this make sense, even in 2NF form? Is this a FACT TABLE?

Comment: @clifton Actally its a interview question

Comment: Actually there are many ways to solve problem and a lot of hidden bugs and secrets. The best answer "It depends". You can create separate index on each column or as point @scaisEdge
"on the columns (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)"
You also can create partitions, refactore tables and so on.
You tell us that it is an interview question, then you should offer as many variants as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best performance are obtained when you create and index on all the column involved in  where  .. and possibly  also on the column involved in select so the index .. is used also per retrive the value ..

In you case  on the column ..

```
 (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)
```

for the filter performance ..and possibile on other column for the avoid the access to data table for retrive information

You can have some tips here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_in.htm

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Remenber that the tuning is DB Product related ..